# Added Sentry debugging, getting long string as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, runtime-error, sentry

We're building a Angular 1.x app with Bootstrap components.  We recently added Sentry debugging to site and just got this error:

> 'PAPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGX' is undefined
>
> browser = IE 11.0
> device = Other
> level = error
> logger = javascript
> os = Windows 8.1
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3; MDDCJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko

I found a couple of references on Twitter but nothing else.  Anyone seen this before? How can I fix this?

Comment: It appears others are experiencing this as well (including my company, just today): https://twitter.com/dpaola2/status/491433981942829057

Comment: Any ideas?  Only on IE11 - still seeing this pop up sometimes

Comment: Seen today from IE11 on windows 8.1. Looks like hacker activity but doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Possibly related? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65abb72a-9d4f-4881-a534-6f75c4b8b498/unknown-error-in-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web?forum=vsdebug

Comment: When you remove the `sentry` from the site, does the error disappear?

Answer (score 6):

That's probably a malware works, mostly reported on windows platform. As you can see from the question, comments and from the internet; all reported for windows systems. According to few malicious activity logging/analysis/reporting service (see ref links below); the malware writes/ends the file with a series of “PADDINGPADDINGXX” strings.

Search in extracted strings section of following sites

- https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/90fa224a030dc8c20e31bc5a6bd02885605e36d01646f40151ba23741830efb7?environmentId=1
- https://totalhash.cymru.com/analysis/?d88d47519bcc49b5c3b345e98e87d20b8928a2c3
- https://www.reverse.it/sample/8cb0a45f5a071c0f521a8afb62335e23fdcc3a3e06bac9a392bff1a89b40cf8c?environmentId=100
- https://www.reverse.it/sample/3f62bec0770de977b84b61c4f72813120f8d6fb6eb4caf96dc7e8e7b4676e444?environmentId=100
- https://www.zscaler.com/blogs/research/current-trojan-ambler-activity
- https://malwr.com/analysis/MzIyYmFkMWM1M2FmNDVlM2JlZjBmYmYwZmM4NDIwMTI/

Comment: A "probably" won't do :-) We already know that all reported systems are Windows 8 and I think all reported browsers are IE11. So that's nothing new. I want somebody to break open one of these wares and show us the insides.

Comment: Thats for collaboration, So that i can update post accordingly. I also noticed that same thing reported on other sites in similar or near by time of 2016. Wondering such thing still happening.

Answer (score 3):

This is a speculative answer. But I intend this to be a resource collection of links pointing towards understanding this issue. Feel free to improve this!

- Malware analysis of [rtfn.exe](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/90fa224a030dc8c20e31bc5a6bd02885605e36d01646f40151ba23741830efb7?environmentId=1)
- [Visual Studio error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65abb72a-9d4f-4881-a534-6f75c4b8b498/unknown-error-in-visual-studio-express-2012-for-web?forum=vsdebug) :: Error occurring due to one click amazon toolbar
- [Bloated application size](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1e3bc7a2-2de0-4fa0-8ebe-0d02dc7256c8/executable-size-versus-object?forum=vcgeneral)
- [Releasing a game for different platforms](http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/wiki/Releasing_a_game_on_iOS) :: It states the following:

  > ac2game.dat is just your windows .exe renamed. You can snip out the unnecessary executable parts by opening it in a hex editor and searching for the string "PADDING". There is a block of text that repeats "PADDINGXX" for a bit, then "CLIB". Chop out everything before CLIB (but leave CLIB). This saves a little space.
- [Extracting resources with dlls](http://www.progtown.com/topic182588-extraction-from-resources-dll-with-resources.html)
- [4 lines PADDINGXX at the end of executable](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/34694-paddingxx/)
- [interesting IRC log](http://infobot.rikers.org/%23wowuidev/20080708.html.gz)

  > It's always good to sumble upon a good 1.8k block of "PADDINGXXPADDINGXXPADDINGXX"

All of this leads me to believe that this **occurs when memory is allocated, but not utilised**. So in your case IE spaghetti code must have picked up some of this.